# Trying to Merging Two grouped queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to get a list of all the clicks and sales associated with an account, with both tables having the account ID as an index.  Right now I have:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(REVENUE) AS R, COUNT(*) AS SALES
FROM CONVERSIONS
WHERE ACCOUNT = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ACCOUNT
```

AND

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, COUNT(DISTINCT BIN_IP) AS CLICKS
FROM CLICKS
WHERE ACCOUNT = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ACCOUNT
```

That gives me both lists, but then I have to do a ton of array manipulation to get them to uniquely line up.  Trying to see if there's a way to join both queries, but thus far everything I've tried has failed.

Edit:  For clarity, my issue with every join I've tried is I lose the case that theres sales and no clicks, or clicks and no sales.  Joining them and checking that the table.ACCOUNT = table2.ACCOUNT only works if there's both clicks and sales present.  This is essentially the part of the puzzle I'm struggling with.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a FULL OUTER JOIN, unfortunately that doesn't exist in mySql, but it can be simulated by doing a left outer join both ways and unioning the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with the queries you have, you can use:

```
SELECT conv.ACCOUNT, conv.R, conv.SALES, clicks.CLICKS
FROM
(SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(REVENUE) AS R, COUNT(*) AS SALES
 FROM CONVERSIONS
 WHERE ACCOUNT = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ACCOUNT) conv
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ACCOUNT, COUNT(DISTINCT BIN_IP) AS CLICKS
 FROM CLICKS
 WHERE ACCOUNT = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ACCOUNT) clicks
ON conv.ACCOUNT = clicks.ACCOUNT
UNION
SELECT clicks2.ACCOUNT, conv2.R, conv2.SALES, clicks2.CLICKS
FROM
(SELECT ACCOUNT, COUNT(DISTINCT BIN_IP) AS CLICKS
 FROM CLICKS
 WHERE ACCOUNT = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ACCOUNT) clicks2
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(REVENUE) AS R, COUNT(*) AS SALES
 FROM CONVERSIONS
 WHERE ACCOUNT = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ACCOUNT) conv2
ON clicks2.ACCOUNT = conv2.ACCOUNT
```

This is messy because mySQL does not have a FULL JOIN. So instead you have to use two left join and UNION. Note that the first set of joins, conv and clicks, will include cases where there are only conversion records and where there are records in both tables. The second set of joins, conv2 and clicks2, will return cases where there are only clicks.

Comment: Same Problem, you lose cases that there's clicks and no sales or sales and no clicks.

Comment: Holy Hell I think that did it, thank you very, very much I've been beating my head on this for a while, and you're right I basically wanted FULL JOIN, and was failing miserably at figuring out a workaround.

Comment: For clarity though, it looks like this essentially doubles my CPU overhead on the queries?  If that's the case maybe I should just stick to the array manipulation if this is the best way to recreate FULL JOIN capability.

Comment: Right... If you can you might consider doing the left joins and union first and then doing all your aggregation at once. The above just gives you purely how to join those two outputs

Comment: Well I really appreciate the help regardless, as it's helped me understand how join\merge works in tandem a lot better. I was hoping there was a sensical workaround I wasn't understanding with mySQL. Seems like just getting the output and manipulating the arrays the way I need is gunna be the lowest overhead solution for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

it may be easier to add colums clicks to your first select, and column r and sales to the second one.( set these to 0 in the select)

Then you can do a union  of the two selects and group by column account. you needs to use sum for the sales,clicks and r columns.

after this you can do a left join the accounts-table with the result to get all accounts (also those without clicks and sales)